# Remove/Add Class on menu hover

Tags: javascript, event-listener

I have tried so many ways to simply get a class to change on an image when I hover over a menu item and it is driving me bonkers. If someone can help me get this straight I would appreciate some help... In the end I will have three of these in place, one for Red, Yellow, and Blue... here is what I have for one example...

```
<script>
const triggerRed = document.getElementsByClassName('gardenBtn');
const redIMG = document.getElementById('gardenMe');
// ️ Change
triggerRed.addEventListener('mouseover', function handleMouseOver() {
  list = redIMG.classList;
  list.remove('risoMe');
});
// ️ Change back
triggerRed.addEventListener('mouseout', function handleMouseOut() {
  list = redIMG.classList;
  list.add('risoMe');
}); 
</script>
```

But nothing changes

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a whole collection of items and you have to add your event listeners to each item, not the whole collection.

Comment: Code doesn't belong in comments.  Please see [ask], then provide enough information so we can answer. Some HTML would be great, in a snippet demo using the editor.